# Pig Storage - Strange empty string

Tags: python, pandas, apache-pig

PigStorage stores empty string with a single double quote caracter :["] rather an expected double single quote : [''] or double double quote : [""].

So when I read the resulting csv with python/pandas, it doesn't work because pandas is lost on the number of fields as soon as it encounters a single double quote (interpreting it as the beginning of a string). 
How could I either :

1)  ask Pig to change its default encoding  of empty string to a double quote ?

2) explain to python/pandas that empty strings are encoded with a simple double quote ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd go for 1), it looks like Pig is the odd one here IMO

Comment: How does Pig handle quoting or escaping delimiters? For that matter, how does it handle a column whose actual value is `"`? If it doesn't use `"` for any of those purposes, you can just tell Python to treat `"` as a normal character, and then post-process the results to convert every single-character `"` into an empty string.

Comment: Meanwhile, do you have any documentation on Pig's CSV dialect that you can link to? If they're doing something this weird, I'll bet they acknowledge it and give some clue how they expect to interoperate with other programs.

Comment: From a quick google, it looks like PigStorage has a CSVExcelStorage subtype, which claims to follow the exact same rules as Excel, which both Pandas and the Python csv module already handle out of the box. Can you use that instead of whatever you're using?